# Dependent events vs. independent events with varying probabilities of success

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Can dependent events be expressed as independent events whose probability of occurring changes based on previous outcomes?

For example, say that I wish to find the chances of me winning a replacement-based game of cards. I know that each draw depends on the other one and technically these events are dependent. However, could I still express the events as independent *if* I specify that the probabilities of winning are allowed to change depending on the cards I've already received?

edit: I can rephrase the question a bit. Let $A_{1}$ denote the first card shown, $A_{2}$, and so on. I know that $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are dependent events, so $$\Pr(A_{2} \ | \ A_{1}) \neq \Pr(A_{2}),$$ which I'm cool with. My question is if I could create a $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ that still denote the first and second card shown **and** satisfies $$\Pr(B_{2} \ | \ B_{1}) = \Pr(B_{2}),$$
**if** I specify that $\Pr(B_{2}) = \Pr(A_{2} \ | \ A_{1})$? I'm running low on sleep so this may not be a good idea.

Comment: If you are careful... for certain types of events... yes, but I wonder why you are trying to do this in the first place.  If your goal is to multiply probabilities to get the probability of intersections, you can do that with dependent events in the first place.  $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B\mid A)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz it was manly for the difference of the sum of Bernoulli trials with fixed $p$ (Binomial) and those with variable $p$ (Poisson-Binomial), since both require independent events. I have to apologize in advance if my question isn't a good one, am running low on sleep and will take a nap.